# C: Empty case before default, useless?

Tags: c, switch-statement, case

In a program, I saw code like this (simplyfied):

```
switch (x){
    case 1:
        //dostuff
        break;

    /*___________________*/
    //Here it is important
    case 2:
    default:
        //dostuff
        break;
}
```

Now I was wondering why someone writes a case and leaves it empty before the default case.

(Clearly it would make sense before another `case`).

I know that in C, there is a fallthrough if there is no `break`, so if `x` is 2, the program runs in the `case 2:` part, and directly falls through to the default-case.

So is the `case 2:`-case useless, since there is no code in it, and `default` will be done also without the label, so the same things are done with and without the case?

Is there a reason to write code like this (like easier modification when maintaining, but in my opinion not really relevant), or did the programmer just not remove it by mistake?

I have used `switch` several times in different languages, but never would have needed such code...

Comment: It may be left in error (as you suggest) -- it also may be a reminder to the original dev to come back to that point as the value 2 might be a value which crops up in regular execution. The effect on runtime decisions is nothing -- indeed, a good compiler should chuck out the case.

Comment: Code is not just for compiling. Code is mostly for reading. Code like that shows the intent that this is a case worth considering on its own even though its implementation happens to match the default.

Comment: Possibly could have been done to make it clear that x=2 causes the default action.

Comment: How simplified your example is? is `x` an enum?

Comment: No, x is an int, but can get only some values according to the program. It is simplified by removing cases, and change the values, to 1 and 2.

Comment: It documents that the person intended case 2 to have the same behaviour as the default case; and they didn't just forget about it

Comment: some coding guides force people to always have a "default" in a switch statement, so even if there's only case 1 and case 2 possible, the "default" is set to act the same way case 2 does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason for it. The explicit `case 2` could be an attempt of writing self-documenting code, but here it doesn't really add anything, as the code lacks meaningful comments that explain what's unique with case 2.

Sometimes you could write code like this to explicitly document to the reader that you have considered all possible values that a variable can have. For example such self-documenting code might make sense with enums.

In this case, it really just looks like it is code still in development. Or it's some sloppily written left-overs that made it to the production code.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I used MISRA C (embedded C rules for vehicles), all switch statements had to have a default clause.  Potentially, this could be a reason for what you are seeing, as this would mean that ALL values passed into the switch would do something.  Admittedly, that would mean the case 2 is redundant, but it might make things clearer when reading the code as a whole.  It could also be some sort of embedded compiler optimisation (sometimes embedded compilers generate more efficient code when given a switch, rather than several ifs).

Comment: MISRA only enforces the default clause. And the reason is defensive programming, it is not there for writing self-documenting code. Although I suppose defensive programming and self-documenting code are often related.